# Serving Python website on it's own server next to apache serving other websites

Tags: php, python

I have Apache server serving several PHP driven websites. I'm developing a websites in Python/Pyramid and want to host it on the same server. What options do I have available?

Answer (score 1):

You have [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), and you have running it as a separate daemon on a different port or interface.

Answer (score 1):

- Apacehe and [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)
- Nginx and [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)

These are the two ways I've done it in the past.